# How many NFTs can a smart contract hold

Tags: blockchain, solidity, nft

I know there is many mappings inside of an ERC721 contracts so let’s say this contract has about 2 million NFTs unlike the original 10k. Will this cause contract to freeze or stop working. Or is there no limit?

Mapping(uint256 => address)

Answer (score 0):

The [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) standard does not define any limit on how many NFTs can be in a collection, apart from token IDs being defined by an `uint256` datatype.

Which means the technical limit is 2^256, which is approximately 10^77.